# iterating over Alloy relation

Tags: iteration, relation, alloy

I have the following signatures :

```
open util/ordering [Graph] as chain

sig Graph { elements : set Node}
sig Node {}
sig Connexion {path : Node  ->  Node}
fact { all c : Connexion | #dom[c.path] = 1}
fact { no c : Connexion | dom[c.path] in ran[c.path]}
```

Where a path is the connexion between a source node and one or multiple sink nodes.
There is only one source for a connexion and a source is not in the sinks.
These parts belongs to a bigger complicated alloy model.

Here is my problem : 
When I want to iterate over paths with :

```
all p : C1.path | one c : C2 | C2.path = this/associatedPath[p]
```

Where C1 and C2 are 2 distinct sets of connections and associatedPath a function that return the mapping path to the parameter path.

The point is when I just try with just only this part in a separate model, it works.
But when I try in the bigger model it returns me :

```
Analysis cannot be performed since it requires higher-order
quantification that could not be skolemized.
```

Is there any things not to do when one iterate over relation?
I also tried to change the quantifier all to some but each time I refer to a tuple, the solver returns me this error.
Is there any way to skolemize it manually?
Is there any reason that I cannot manipulate relation in expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say: "a path is the connexion between a source node and one or multiple sink nodes". Do you mean a "connexion is a path..."? Either way, perhaps your Connexion signature can be rewritten

`sig Connexion {from: Node, to: set Node}`

That will dramatically reduce the complexity. It may not eliminate the skolemization problem. To address that you should quantify over Connexion:

`all c: Connexion | ...`

Comment: Yes, a connexion is a path.
You say : "That will dramatically reduce the complexity".
Expressing the  connexion as a 2 fielded signature than expressing as signature with a relation between Node. Normally the 2 signatures should be quite equivalent, aren't they?
As Alloy use a relational algebra, is it better to express  relations as relation with arity of 2 like the path relation, or with 2 relations of arity 1 like you express it?
What are the complexity impacts?
Is  there any impact on the solving performance?
Are there any good practices in these cases?